# How can I center images in a slideshow?

Tags: jquery, image, slideshow, center

I'm made a slideshow following [this tutorial](http://www.nitinh.com/2010/03/how-to-create-a-simple-slideshow-using-mootools-jquery/). However, I'm using images of varying widths so I want them centered.

My best guess was changing

```
$(indexImage).css({'display':'block', 'opacity':1});
```

to

```
$(indexImage).css({'display':'block','margin':'auto', 'opacity':1});
```

After a couple hours of trying many things, I decided to hit the forums.

But I'm having no luck. [Here's my jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/KzfgH/), can anyone help me out?

Thanks

Comment: your fiddle doesn't run. I'd start with absolute links...

Comment: When you make a fiddle, it'd be useful to set `jQuery` as the framework and actually include some URLs which point to images. Also, that tutorial has some poor practices in it.

Comment: agreed, that tutorial is pretty tragic. If you're looking for a slider there are millions that actually work. If you're looking to learn, try to use tutorials from more popular sources, instead of someone's blog http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2011/07/15/orbit-and-reveal-jquery-plug-ins-that-will-breathe-life-into-your-pages/

Comment: I see, thanks for the tips, will do. However, if anyone can still figure out how to center the images it'd be great. I updated the jsfiddle (so the 6th image should be centered). Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than use the large images, you could instead use divs that are sized to the full height and width, then set the image as the `background-image` of each div. Then, you can set the `background-position: 50% 50%` which will perfectly center the images.

If you want, you can use the not-quite-cross-browser css style `background-size: contain` to make sure the image completely fits within the provided space.

Answer (score 0):

There is a jQuery plugin for this:

http://boxlight.github.com/bl-jquery-image-center/